# Unable to install PyAudio on M1 Mac [PortAudio already installed]

Tags: pip, homebrew, pyaudio, macos-big-sur, portaudio

I have visited many forums, tried diffrent methods like brew, pip, port and many more but still am facing the same error.

[View this Image for more detail](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4YmQF.png)

```
src/_portaudiomodule.c:29:10: fatal error: 'portaudio.h' file not found
    #include "portaudio.h"
             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
    1 error generated.
    error: command '/usr/bin/gcc' failed with exit code 1
```

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This Solution is tested on M1 Macs[Please do check with other].

After the installation of HomeBrew on your system, perform the installation of **PortAudio**. Next follow the steps mentioned below:

Use the command to install **PortAudio**

> sudo brew install portaudio

After successful installation of **PortAudio**, enter the following command.

> sudo nano $HOME/.pydistutils.cfg

Next, enter the following lines in the opened window

```
[build_ext]
include_dirs=/Users/<enter-your-system-username>/homebrew/Cellar/portaudio/19.20140130/include/
include_dirs=/Users/<enter-your-system-username>/homebrew/Cellar/portaudio/19.20140130/lib/
```

**Note: PortAudio location may be different for you and also don't forget to replace your PC username.**

Finally run the command

> pip install pyaudio

or

> pip3 install pyaudio

Comment: This solution worked for me, but at first I was getting this error:
`pydistutils.cfg' [line 3]: option 'include_dirs' in section 'build_ext' already exists`. After the first `include_dirs`, I added a new section `build_ext_1` for the second `include_dirs` and it worked.

Comment: @shend What was the lines you wrote? I'm not sure I understand but same error as you.

Comment: You can't run home brew as root anymore. So first follow this solution, https://stackoverflow.com/a/34175205/3940670 . Then try the brew commands with no sudo.

Answer (score 37):

These steps worked on M1 Pro chips

1. Install `portaudio`

```
brew install portaudio
```

2. Link `portaudio`

```
brew link portaudio
```

3. Copy the path where `portaudio` was installed (use it in the next step)

```
brew --prefix portaudio
```

4. Create `.pydistutils.cfg` in your home directory

```
sudo nano $HOME/.pydistutils.cfg
```

then paste the following

```
[build_ext]
include_dirs=<PATH FROM STEP 3>/include/
library_dirs=<PATH FROM STEP 3>/lib/
```

5. Install pyaudio

```
pip install pyaudio

or

pip3 install pyaudio
```

Comment: thanks, selected! it works for me! Step 3 is the gold~!

Answer (score 12):

For me it was:

```
brew install portaudio
python -m pip install --global-option='build_ext' --global-option='-I/opt/homebrew/Cellar/portaudio/19.7.0/include' --global-option='-L/opt/homebrew/Cellar/portaudio/19.7.0/lib' pyaudio
```

Comment: I just did `brew install portaudio` and everything was fine.

Answer (score 4):

The main challenge we're encountering here is that pyaudio doesn't know where to find the portaudio libraries since, according to the source, it only looks in these locations for darwin platform installations:

```
include_dirs += ['/usr/local/include', '/usr/include']
external_libraries_path += ['/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib']
```

This won't do if you're using a homebrew installation of portaudio, particularly so with Apple Silicon since there isn't a pre-built wheel in PyPi. This means setuptools/pip will need to build the package from source.

There are a few ways of [configuring setuptools](https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/extension.html?highlight=include#defining-additional-metadata) to use additional paths, including [passing arguments](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/cli/pip_install/#cmdoption-install-option), using a [.pydistutils.cfg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25914145/whats-pydistutils-cfg-for) file, among others, but the second option worked for me given I'm installing pyaudio to a few Python environments.

Building off of some of the answers above, you can copy the following  below to install pyaudio in one go.

```bash
# Install portaudio, will print list of paths where it's been installed if already done
brew list portaudio || brew install portaudio
# Link portaudio, will print a warning if already linked
brew link portaudio
# Create a pydistutils config file with the portaudio lib paths set correctly (no copying/pasting paths required)
cat <<EOF >> .pydistutils.cfg
[build_ext]
include_dirs=`brew --prefix portaudio`/include/
library_dirs=`brew --prefix portaudio`/lib/
EOF
# install (build) package with pip
python -m pip install pyaudio
```

All we're doing is telling setuptools to also look for C/C++ headers where portaudio has been installed by homebrew.

Comment: After so many trials I finally found something that worked! I tried with the global config for pip, but id didn't work. This solution seems to work instead

Comment: after running this script, unfortunately I get this error on m1.

  src/_portaudiomodule.c:31:10: fatal error: 'portaudio.h' file not found
      #include "portaudio.h"

Comment: if anybody knows how to fix, that help would be, well... helpful.

Answer (score 2):

vkshah has an error in his second line.  It should ready `library_dirs` instead of `include_dirs`:

````
include_dirs=/Users/<enter-your-system-username>/homebrew/Cellar/portaudio/19.20140130/include/
library_dirs=/Users/<enter-your-system-username>/homebrew/Cellar/portaudio/19.20140130/lib/```
````

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31594722)

Comment: It does "provide answers that don't require a clarification from the asker", namely that the answer given by vkshah had a typo that would have made it incorrect.  On top of the code snippets, I gave an explanation that was pretty darned clear (library_dirs instead of include_dirs). So, would you rather have the vkshah's original answer stand (which I am very thankful for, as I was completely stuck, and this got me 95% there), or have the correct answer that would actually solve users' problems?

Comment: Hi, I'm sorry for the words above.  I didn't expect that my choice in the moderator review queue would trigger some rude automatic bot reply like that.  I fully agree and appreciate your errata about vkshah's answer.  However, I would suggest to use the "edit" or "improve this answer" link under vkshah's answer instead, which is more friendly to future readers.  After the community volunteers accept your improvements, you will be credited in the original answer as an editor, and this separate answer entry could be deleted then.

Answer (score 2):

For me, I am running **Big Sur** on an **M1** Mac. I followed all the instructions mentioned in other threads to:

1. install portaudio

   `arch -arm64 brew install portaudio`
2. start a venv

   `python3 -m venv env`

   `source env/bin/activate`
3. install pyaudio

   `arch -arm64 pip install --no-cache-dir --global-option='build_ext' --global-option='-I/opt/homebrew/include' --global-option='-L/opt/homebrew/lib' pyaudio==0.2.11`

*TIP #1*

If you see error on `portaudio.h file not found`, the solution is **specifying the pyaudio version** at the end. Because it kept trying to install version '0.2.12' which failed. I specify the version of pyaudio to '0.2.11' (see above).

*TIP #2*

After successfully installing pyaudio, you may see error `PyAudio C module _portaudio`, that is due to `pip` built it(`_portaudio.cpython-36m-darwin.so`) in x86_64 architecture. It's not compatible with arm64 portaudio, in this case, make sure to include `arch -arm64` in front of pip to build the correct binary.

*TIP #3*

Use an older version of python, I personally used version `3.6`.

Oh, and make sure the **single quote** is actually `'` if you copied the command from a text editor.
Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

first you need to download portaudio using homebrew

> brew install portaudio

Then try to install pyaudio directly

> pip install pyaudio

if you are getting error while installing follow below step

Or
if you are facing any error mentioned bellow you can follow these steps

---

### error 1

option 'include_dirs' in section 'build_ext' already exists

---

### error 2

Could not build wheels for pyaudio, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects

---

### error 3

#include "portaudio.h"
^~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
error: command '/usr/bin/clang' failed with exit code 1

---

solution start here

after installing homebrew you have to link it

> brew link portaudio

in some cases it will say that it has been already linked then simply ignore

we need path of portaudio where it is exactly installed

> brew --prefix portaudio

it will gives you path of portaudio

then you have to check if pydistutils.cfg file exists or not

> sudo cat $HOME/.pydistutils.cfg

if file exists then it will open else create it will below command

> sudo cat $HOME/.pydistutils.cfg

so in these file we have to define proper path here

```
[build_ext]
include_dirs=/--PATH--/include/
library_dirs=/--PATH--/lib/
```

you can get that path by running below command

> brew --prefix portaudio

if that path is not working then try below path

```
[build_ext]
include_dirs=/Users/<username>/homebrew/Cellar/portaudio/19.20140130/include/
library_dirs=/Users/<username>/homebrew/Cellar/portaudio/19.20140130/lib/
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use mac os

1. Install Homebrew (insert link into the terminal:

/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)" )

2. Insert command into the terminal:

brew install portaudio

3. Insert command into the terminal:

pip install pyaudio

p.s. sometimes you need upgrade your pip installer

These actions solved my problem (mac os Mojave 10.14.4)