# Mac M1 Can't Install PyAudio / Tried All Answers Suggested in StackOverflow

Tags: python, macos, pip, pyaudio, apple-m1

Mac M1 Can't Install PyAudio | Need Microphone for Google Speech Recognition:

---

Please note below I have outlined answers that have seemed to work for others that have not worked for me.

---

> Below is the error code:
> WARNING: Discarding https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/d0/dc/ffb9ce5e3f19bd289902915a9f68b7d199216065f8ea17d5b5e8e4ad86ee/PyAudio-0.2.9.tar.gz#sha256=bfd694272b3d1efc51726d0c27650b3c3ba1345f7f8fdada7e86c9751ce0f2a1 (from https://pypi.org/simple/pyaudio/). Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
> Using cached pyaudio-0.2.8.tar.gz (235 kB)
> Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... error
> ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
> command: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/bin/python3 -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/lw/_gcm85s107z9sbgqyrw5pw700000gn/T/pip-install-p8wmnhcz/pyaudio_38ac896d11214f37bec552d23eaf6dfc/setup.py'"'"'; **file**='"'"'/private/var/folders/lw/_gcm85s107z9sbgqyrw5pw700000gn/T/pip-install-p8wmnhcz/pyaudio_38ac896d11214f37bec552d23eaf6dfc/setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(**file**) if os.path.exists(**file**) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base /private/var/folders/lw/_gcm85s107z9sbgqyrw5pw700000gn/T/pip-pip-egg-info-nt0b4dbj
> cwd: /private/var/folders/lw/_gcm85s107z9sbgqyrw5pw700000gn/T/pip-install-p8wmnhcz/pyaudio_38ac896d11214f37bec552d23eaf6dfc/
> Complete output (15 lines):
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "", line 1, in 
> File "/private/var/folders/lw/_gcm85s107z9sbgqyrw5pw700000gn/T/pip-install-p8wmnhcz/pyaudio_38ac896d11214f37bec552d23eaf6dfc/setup.py", line 124, in 
> setup(name = 'PyAudio',
> File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/distutils/core.py", line 121, in setup
> dist.parse_config_files()
> File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 776, in parse_config_files
> self._parse_config_files(filenames=filenames)
> File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 648, in _parse_config_files
> parser.read_file(reader)
> File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/configparser.py", line 719, in read_file
> self._read(f, source)

---

> WARNING: Discarding https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/06/d1/3d202c9187fb78ad6d4f8b476a8cc0ded7c1b47ca33d5dab73b959faf123/pyaudio-0.2.8.tar.gz#sha256=4f85367cf79657616684487037957ac38582ecc5389b89420fe61d901b719551 (from https://pypi.org/simple/pyaudio/). Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
> ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pyaudio (from versions: 0.2.8, 0.2.9, 0.2.10, 0.2.11)
> ERROR: No matching distribution found for pyaudio
> WARNING: You are using pip version 21.3; however, version 21.3.1 is available.
> You should consider upgrading via the '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/bin/python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.

---

Please note what was attempted through answers on stackoverflow and other-sites that has not worked for me.

---

brew update
brew install portaudio
brew link --overwrite portaudio
pip install pyaudio

---

##Use the command to install PortAudio

sudo brew install portaudio

##After successful installation of PortAudio, enter the following command.

sudo nano $HOME/.pydistutils.cfg

##Next, enter the following lines in the opened window

[build_ext]
include_dirs=/Users//homebrew/Cellar/portaudio/19.20140130/include/
include_dirs=/Users//homebrew/Cellar/portaudio/19.20140130/lib/

Finally run the command

pip install pyaudio

or

pip3 install pyaudio

---

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+fatal+error+portaudio.h+file+not+found

Answer (score 0):

install `brew` on your M1 machine from here

[How to install homebrew on M1 mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66666134/how-to-install-homebrew-on-m1-mac)

And then enter this commands :

```
brew update
brew install portaudio
brew link --overwrite portaudio
pip install pyaudio
```

you can also check this :

[Unable to install PyAudio on M1 Mac [PortAudio already installed]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68251169/unable-to-install-pyaudio-on-m1-mac-portaudio-already-installed)

Comment: Freeman thank you for the suggestion.  Did everything you suggested and still getting the error. Below is the exact response from the actions you listed.

Comment: user@MacBook-Air ~ % brew update
Updated 2 taps (homebrew/core and homebrew/cask).

Comment: user@MacBook-Air ~ % brew install portaudio
Warning: portaudio 19.7.0 is already installed and up-to-date.
To reinstall 19.7.0, run:
  brew reinstall portaudio

Comment: user@MacBook-Air ~ % brew link --overwrite portaudio
Warning: Already linked: /opt/homebrew/Cellar/portaudio/19.7.0
To relink, run:
  brew unlink portaudio && brew link portaudio

Comment: user@MacBook-Air ~ % pip install pyaudio

Comment: Still shooting the exact same error

Comment: that's ok @OHP, just run step by step like me : (1) brew reinstall portaudio

Comment: (2) brew unlink portaudio && brew link portaudio

Comment: (3) pip install pyaudio

Comment: after this steps if it shows you any error send it to me again , thnx

Comment: Last login: Wed Oct 27 23:54:56 on ttys002
user@MacBook-Air ~ % pip install pyaudio
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pyaudio (from versions: 0.2.8, 0.2.9, 0.2.10, 0.2.11)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for pyaudio

Comment: Thanks @Freeman want to send you the whole error code "sent you the end, but it is a long one" , but don't know how, a little new to this appreciate the help.

Comment: WARNING: Discarding https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/06/d1/3d202c9187fb78ad6d4f8b476a8cc0ded7c1b47ca33d5dab73b959faf123/pyaudio-0.2.8.tar.gz#sha256=4f85367cf79657616684487037957ac38582ecc5389b89420fe61d901b719551 (from https://pypi.org/simple/pyaudio/). Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.

Comment: Don't know if this matters, however, ran:

Comment: brew doctor and received this message

Comment: Warning: A '.pydistutils.cfg' file was found in $HOME, which may cause Python
builds to fail. See:
  https://bugs.python.org/issue6138
  https://bugs.python.org/issue4655

Comment: where r u from ? and do you have anydesk ?