# Cannot for the life of me get portaudio install on my M1Pro Macbook Pro

Tags: python, macos, pyaudio, portaudio

```
    sudo -H pip install pyaudio --global-option="build_ext" --global-option="-I/opt/homebrew/include" --global-option="-L/opt/homebrew/lib"
WARNING: Disabling all use of wheels due to the use of --build-option / --global-option / --install-option.
Collecting pyaudio
  Downloading PyAudio-0.2.12.tar.gz (42 kB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 42.9/42.9 kB 872.0 kB/s eta 0:00:00
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Installing backend dependencies ... done
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... done
Building wheels for collected packages: pyaudio
  Building wheel for pyaudio (pyproject.toml) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Building wheel for pyaudio (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [16 lines of output]
      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      running build_py
      creating build
      creating build/lib.macosx-12-arm64-cpython-39
      copying src/pyaudio.py -> build/lib.macosx-12-arm64-cpython-39
      running build_ext
      building '_portaudio' extension
      creating build/temp.macosx-12-arm64-cpython-39
      creating build/temp.macosx-12-arm64-cpython-39/src
      clang -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -isysroot /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX12.sdk -DMACOSX=1 -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/include -I/opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.13_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/include/python3.9 -c src/_portaudiomodule.c -o build/temp.macosx-12-arm64-cpython-39/src/_portaudiomodule.o
      src/_portaudiomodule.c:31:10: fatal error: 'portaudio.h' file not found
      #include "portaudio.h"
               ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
      1 error generated.
      error: command '/usr/bin/clang' failed with exit code 1
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for pyaudio
Failed to build pyaudio
ERROR: Could not build wheels for pyaudio, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

When I run the command, no matter what - pip install pyaudio, or the above command with/without sudo it always gives the same error. I see this is a very common issue. I double checked the path and portaudio in the directory used in the command. I am at a loss and really do not understand why it is not working. I also tried building pyaudio directly from the file itself and it  still doesn't work. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I guess I'm asking for any advice as to how to install pyaudio on my device. Or if anyone has any experience with the same problem

Comment: Maybe look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68251169/unable-to-install-pyaudio-on-m1-mac-portaudio-already-installed

Comment: @Bobth I did try that as well and it is not working

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED: I found this: https://qiita.com/yukilab/items/d50a10f1d46c44ae0757

even though it is in another language I was able to get it working. It is similar to what was suggested by @Bob th but slightly different.

In essence I made a file .pydistutils.cfg and added

```
    [build_ext]
include_dirs=/opt/homebrew/include
library_dirs=/opt/homebrew/lib
```