# ERROR: Could not build wheels for pyaudio, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects

Tags: python, homebrew, pyproject.toml

I'm getting this error when trying to install PyAudio:

```
ERROR: Could not build wheels for pyaudio, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

Does anyone know why this is happening and how to solve?

Best

Comment: always put FULL error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information in the full error/traceback.

Comment: when you run `pip` then you  may use option `-v` (like `verbose`) to see more information when `pip` displays error. Without FULL error it is hard to say what is the problem. As I know `PyAudio` may use some C/C++ code and it may have problem with compilation. It may need to use `homebrew` in install some C/C++ libraries or C/C++ source codes with files `.h`. But all this need more information about error. OR you should check other question for this problem with `PyAudio`

Comment: Hi @furas thanks for your reply - I have included the full message below

Comment: Acredito que esse link pode lhe ajudar [PyAudio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48690984/portaudio-h-no-such-file-or-directory)

Comment: @penguin-dev 's solution in the comments below solved my issue, in case this is something you still haven't figured out.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to install PyAudio on M1 Mac \[PortAudio already installed\]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68251169/unable-to-install-pyaudio-on-m1-mac-portaudio-already-installed)

Answer (score 58):

Try this [solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xn0bm.png):

These steps worked on M1 Pro chips

1. Install `portaudio`

```
brew install portaudio
```

2. Link `portaudio`

```
brew link portaudio
```

3. Copy the path where `portaudio` was installed (use it in the next step)

```
brew --prefix portaudio
```

4. Create `.pydistutils.cfg` in your home directory

```
sudo nano $HOME/.pydistutils.cfg
```

then paste the following

```
[build_ext]
include_dirs=<PATH FROM STEP 3>/include/
library_dirs=<PATH FROM STEP 3>/lib/
```

5. Install pyaudio

```
pip install pyaudio

or

pip3 install pyaudio
```

from: [Unable to install PyAudio on M1 Mac [PortAudio already installed]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68251169/unable-to-install-pyaudio-on-m1-mac-portaudio-already-installed)

Comment: Answer the question in text not as a screenshot

Comment: This helped fix my pyaudio install issues. Thank you! This works for M1 chip macOS issues.

Comment: many thanks!! -- from a M1 user

Comment: You are a genius! Repaired my issue on an M1 mac.

Comment: 2018 mac intel works as well!

Comment: For me, a mere `brew install portaudio` was enough in Intel Mac

Comment: I hadn't seen heilala's comment, but I didn't use `sudo` in step 4 and my problem is resolved.

Comment: for me the key was to use pip3 instead of pip

Answer (score 38):

Developments files are needed.  Those files are installed with the `portaudio19-dev` package.

```
sudo apt install portaudio19-dev
```

Comment: this also work on ubuntu 22! thanks

Comment: Worked on Ubuntu 23.04

Comment: Worked on Ubuntu 20.04, thank you

Comment: Also works in Debian 12

Answer (score 0):

I had this error building my own package and it was fixed by ending the pip install statement with `--user`

Answer (score 0):

you can use below line for Mac OS

```
$ python3 -m venv tensorflow-metal-test
$ source tensorflow-metal-test/bin/activate
$ cd tensorflow-metal-test/
$ python -m pip install -U pip
$ pip install tensorflow-macos
$ pip install tensorflow-metal
```